# KeyErrors in Python script

Tags: pyqgis, html

I'm using a script in the QGIS python console to extract an HTML attributes code in KMLs files that convert to JSON, but for some of them, I get a KeyErrors.

This is the script that I used:

https://github.com/planemad/qgis-extract-html-attributes/blob/master/extract_html_attributes.py

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ast

# PyQGIS function to extract HTML attributes encoded in a string into seperate field
# Useful for converting data from GeoRSS to other formats
# Instructions are specific to GeoRSS XML data downloaded from Bhuvan geoserver https://bhuvan-vec1.nrsc.gov.in
# For other sources the parse_HTML_attributes function needs to be customized
# 1. Open the GeoRSS XML data and export the data to an editable format like GeoPackage or GeoJSON 
# 2. Select the exported layer in the layer list
# 3. Open `Plugins > Python Console`and run the script from the code editor
# 4. Open the layer attribute table to verify the parsed HTML values
# Processing can take around 1 minute for 5,000 features. The processing can be limited to specific features in the layer by selecting it first.

def parse_HTML_attributes(feature):
    "Parse attributes encoded in a HTML string into a dictionary"
    parsed_attributes = {}
    
    # Locate the attribute with the HTML string
    attribute_HTML = BeautifulSoup(feature['description'])
    #print(attribute_HTML) # DEBUG
    
    # Loop through every list item to extract a key value pair
    for attribute_item in attribute_HTML.findAll('li'):
        parsed_attributes.update({attribute_item.find(class_='atr-name').text : attribute_item.find(class_='atr-value').text })
    
    return parsed_attributes
    
def parse_string_type(string):
    "Return the appropriate field attribute type to use from the string value"
    try:
        eval_string = ast.literal_eval(string)
    
    except ValueError:
        return QVariant.String
    except SyntaxError:
        return QVariant.String
    else:
        if type(eval_string) in [int, long,  bool]:
            return QVariant.Int
        if type(eval_string) in [float]:
            return QVariant.Double
        else:
            return QVariant.String

# Work on the actively selected layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Sample 20 features in the layer to find the new fields to add to the layer attribute table
new_fields = {}
# Determine list of features: if a selection exists or take all features in the layer
if layer.selectedFeatureCount() and layer.selectedFeatureCount() < 20:
    feature_list = layer.selectedFeatures() 
else:
    feature_list = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setLimit(20))
    
for feature in feature_list: 
    new_fields.update(parse_HTML_attributes(feature))


try:
    with edit(layer):
        
        # Add the new string fields to the layer attribute table
        for key in new_fields:
            layer.addAttribute(QgsField(key, parse_string_type(new_fields[key])))
            print('Added new field', key, parse_string_type(new_fields[key]))
        
        # Build a list of features to update from the active selection
        feature_list = layer.selectedFeatures() or layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest())
        
        # Update the new attributes with the parsed HTML attributes
        for feature in feature_list:
            parsed_HTML_attributes = parse_HTML_attributes(feature)
            for key in parsed_HTML_attributes:
               feature[key] = parsed_HTML_attributes[key]
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
        print('Features updated')
        
except AssertionError:
    print('Please convert the layer into a QGIS editable format. Geopackage is recommended for fastest result')
```

And this the Errors that I get from it:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~1\QGIS32~1.0\apps\Python39\lib\code.py", line 90, in runcode
    exec(code, self.locals)
  File "<input>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 76, in <module>
KeyError: 'OBJECTID'
```

And this the link for KMLs files:

https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1LkfegaOwgmElr1EAS5NSpjpCehmuYwo4

Comment: It is impossible to download the file without authorization

Comment: Ok, let me see, how about now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem stems from the line 52:

```py
feature_list = layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest().setLimit(20))
```

The new attribute column names are parsed from the first 20 features only, whereas later in the script all the features have their HTML string parsed and an attempt is made to update their fields.

###### The problem:

Features later than 20 have more attributes parsed from their HTML string that were not parsed from the first 20. Therefore, a new field does not exist for them, hence the `KeyError` in the feature's attributes.

I saw it after I realised what was happening, but the clue is in the comment in line 49:

```
# Sample 20 features in the layer to find the new fields to add to the layer attribute table
```

###### The solution:

By saving the KML to a GeoPackage and removing the limit, I was able to run the script successfully.

Full script (with the minor modification of the removed feature limit):

```py
from qgis.PyQt.QtCore import QVariant
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import ast

# PyQGIS function to extract HTML attributes encoded in a string into seperate field
# Useful for converting data from GeoRSS to other formats
# Instructions are specific to GeoRSS XML data downloaded from Bhuvan geoserver https://bhuvan-vec1.nrsc.gov.in
# For other sources the parse_HTML_attributes function needs to be customized
# 1. Open the GeoRSS XML data and export the data to an editable format like GeoPackage or GeoJSON 
# 2. Select the exported layer in the layer list
# 3. Open `Plugins > Python Console`and run the script from the code editor
# 4. Open the layer attribute table to verify the parsed HTML values
# Processing can take around 1 minute for 5,000 features. The processing can be limited to specific features in the layer by selecting it first.

def parse_HTML_attributes(feature):
    "Parse attributes encoded in a HTML string into a dictionary"
    parsed_attributes = {}
    
    # Locate the attribute with the HTML string
    attribute_HTML = BeautifulSoup(feature['description'])
    #print(attribute_HTML) # DEBUG
    
    # Loop through every list item to extract a key value pair
    for attribute_item in attribute_HTML.findAll('li'):
        parsed_attributes.update({attribute_item.find(class_='atr-name').text : attribute_item.find(class_='atr-value').text })
    
    return parsed_attributes
    
def parse_string_type(string):
    "Return the appropriate field attribute type to use from the string value"
    try:
        eval_string = ast.literal_eval(string)
    
    except ValueError:
        return QVariant.String
    except SyntaxError:
        return QVariant.String
    else:
        if type(eval_string) in [int, long,  bool]:
            return QVariant.Int
        if type(eval_string) in [float]:
            return QVariant.Double
        else:
            return QVariant.String

# Work on the actively selected layer
layer = iface.activeLayer()

# Sample 20 features in the layer to find the new fields to add to the layer attribute table
new_fields = {}

#############
# Determine list of features
# QgsFeatureRequest feature limit removed 
#############
feature_list = layer.getFeatures() 
    
for feature in feature_list: 
    new_fields.update(parse_HTML_attributes(feature))
    print(parse_HTML_attributes(feature))


try:
    with edit(layer):
        
        # Add the new string fields to the layer attribute table
        for key in new_fields:
            layer.addAttribute(QgsField(key, parse_string_type(new_fields[key])))
            print('Added new field', key, parse_string_type(new_fields[key]))
        
        # Build a list of features to update from the active selection
        feature_list = layer.selectedFeatures() or layer.getFeatures(QgsFeatureRequest())
        
        # Update the new attributes with the parsed HTML attributes
        for feature in feature_list:
            parsed_HTML_attributes = parse_HTML_attributes(feature)
            print(parsed_HTML_attributes)
            for key in parsed_HTML_attributes:
               feature[key] = parsed_HTML_attributes[key]
            layer.updateFeature(feature)
        print('Features updated')
        
except AssertionError:
    print('Please convert the layer into a QGIS editable format. Geopackage is recommended for fastest result')
```

Comment: It works for me, thanks bro

Answer (score 1):

There  is no OBJECTID tag in the xml(kml) file. As Matt says, OBJECTID is present in the tag description (HTML string) , but not in every feature/row.

With one of your kml file and BeautifulSoup (pure Python):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as Soup
with open('geoportail-secteur.kml') as data:
     kml_soup = Soup(data, 'lxml-xml')
descriptions = kml_soup.find_all('description')
# number of features/rows
print(len(descriptions))
412
# number of features/rows that contain OBJECTID
nb = 0
for description in descriptions:
     html_soup = Soup(description.text, 'lxml') 
     if 'OBJECTID' in html_soup.text:
         nb=nb+1
print(nb)
94
```

With GeoPandas (geospatial):

```
import geopandas as gpd
import fiona
gpd.io.file.fiona.drvsupport.supported_drivers['KML'] = 'rw'
gdf = gpd.read_file('geoportail-secteurs.kml')
# number of features/rows
print(len(gdf))
412
print(gdf.columns) 
Index(['Name', 'Description', 'geometry'], dtype='object')
# number of features/rows that contain OBJECTID
nb = gdf.loc[gdf['Description'].str.contains("OBJECTID", case=True)]
print(nb)
94
```

There are 94 features/rows containing "OBJECTID" out of 412 rows, so when parsing the HTML string -> KeyError: 'OBJECTID' for the other features/rows.

As described in the script (lines 7-8) you need to  customize it for
your data.

Comment: `OBJECTID` is being parsed from a HTML string within one of the other properties (`description`). The problem appears to be that it is not being added to the `new_fields` dictionary.

Comment: @gene, Then how I can customize it?

Comment: @Matt, then how I can solve this?

Comment: "The script is customized to work with GeoRSS vector layers from Bhuvan GeoServer where the feature attributes are stored in the description field as an HTML list." (in [qgis-extract-html-attributes](https://github.com/planemad/qgis-extract-html-attributes)). Therefore you need to modify the original script to adapt it to your files (in def parse_HTML_attributes(feature))